# How to insert multiple selected row values from other table to new table

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server, oracle

> from one Query is it possible to do?

To insert Multiple selected row information from one table to other table
like:

```
Customers (register_no,CustomerName, City, Country)
Suppliers(register_no,SupplierName, City, Country)
```

`INSERT INTO Customers (register_no,CustomerName, City, Country)
SELECT register_no SupplierName, City, Country FROM Suppliers where register_no=10;`

But in one time is it possible to select register_no=1,register_no=3,register_no=10;
in one Query

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes,it is possible by using in

```
INSERT INTO Customers (register_no,CustomerName, City, Country)
SELECT register_no SupplierName, City, Country FROM Suppliers where register_no in (1,3,10)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `IN` clause for this.

```
INSERT INTO Customers (register_no,CustomerName, City, Country)
SELECT register_no SupplierName, City, Country FROM Suppliers where register_no IN (1,3,10);
```